# How do I set the color of UIBarButtonItem under the "More" section of the UIActivityViewController on iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am working on an app that uses UIActivityViewController for social sharing.  iOS8 adds a "More" option.  When I click "More" a navigation bar appears with the title "Activities".  The nav bar has a "Done" option to close, unfortunately I currently have a cream nav bar with a white "Done" button.

**How do I set the color of UIBarButtonItem under the "More" section of the UIActivityViewController on iOS8?**

Comment: swift or objective c?

Comment: objective c but ill accept a swift answer :)

Comment: Also looking for a solution for this, we've got a white on white situation with no way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the following line of code from the AppDelegate

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no documented way of customizing the **Activities screen** of `UIActivityViewController`.

Moreover, `UIActivityViewController` seems not to inherit a parent's `UINavigationController` (navigation bar) appearances like `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController` do.